# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ... on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a class called **ResultActivity** which display a list of place'info. This activity request to server and receive a json object. But my activity doesn't work and I found this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shameal/com.example.shameal.ResultActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader com.example.shameal.controller.AppController.getImageLoader()' on a null object reference
```

**ResultActivity**

```
public class ResultActivity extends ListActivity{
private ListView listView;
private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    ...
}
```

**FeedListAdapter**

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return feedItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView address = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.address);
    TextView description = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.description);
    TextView rate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
    NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.image);
    FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

    FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

    name.setText(item.getName());

    // Converting timestamp into x ago format
    address.setText(item.getAddress());

    // Chcek for empty status message
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getDescription())) {
        description.setText(item.getDescription());
        description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // status is empty, remove from view
        description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    rate.setText(item.getRate());
    image.setImageUrl(item.getImage(), imageLoader);

    // Feed image
    if (item.getMenu() != null || item.getMenu() != "0") {
        feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getMenu(), imageLoader);
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        feedImageView
                .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }
                });
    } else {
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

I think the error in this line: **listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);** but I can not found the solution to fix it.

Thanks for your help!

**Edited**: I followed this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/. I just use the code of this tutorial but my app doesn't work.

Comment: Problem is in `FeedListAdapter` class so please post `FeedListAdapter` class code with question

Comment: You are using `ImageLoader` inside your `FeedListAdapter` class .This null pointer Exception is occurred while you are using that ImageLoader without initializing it something like with `ImageLoader.getInstance()` .

Please post your `FeedListAdapter` so I can give you accurate answer.

Comment: I already post FeedListAdapter in my question

Comment: Oups srry I haven't reloaded page.

You have issue inside `getImageLoader()` method of your `AppController` class.

Comment: I updated my question. I use the same code with that tutorial. I don't understand why my app doesn't work

Comment: Have you done this `AppController extends Application` . and `mInstance = this;` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: I see  feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>(); but I do not see where you add items to it, you are passing an empty ArrayList to your BaseAdapter

Comment: Yes I did it @kibzorg

Comment: @faljbour I get json object from server and put it to feedItems after onCreate(). I have checked it and it work fine so I do not show this code in my question

Comment: so is your code working now, or you still have an issue.

Comment: I still have a problem with the error in my question. I think the this line: "listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);" made it because this point to null (I think that). Is it right?

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I found a way to fix my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add one line to manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController" //this one
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `AppController.getInstance()` returns `null` so when you execute `getImageLoader()`, it fails